# httpclient get and put

Tags: java, httpclient

here is what i want to do and need some help in it.

I have a source url and a destination url. what i want to do is copy a file from a source url to the destination url, but I want to avoid copying the file locally on my system before uploading the file again.

Also what is must to have is that we should get the content-length because the destination api requires it (its custom). If I use the HttpUrlConnection class then i can get that....but AFAIK there are some issues in using java.net for anything other than GET. (the source files are huge image/video files), so i can using apache httpclient 3.1. But how do i approach this?

any thoughts?

-Ash

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

- get the body of the GET response as a stream with [GetMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#getResponseBodyAsStream%28%29)
- and "pipe" it into a the body of the PUT request with [PutMethod.setRequestBody](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#setRequestBody%28java.io.InputStream%29).

See this [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).

**EDIT**

You should be able to get the response size of the `GET` with [GetMethod.getResponseContentLenght](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#getResponseContentLength%28%29) (which corresponds to the `Content-Length` header, if provided).

Then I suggest you look at one of the following for the `PUT` method: [setRequestContentLenght](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#setRequestContentLength(int)), [addContentLenghtRequestHeader](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#addContentLengthRequestHeader(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState,%20org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection)), [setContentChunked](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html#setContentChunked(boolean)).

Comment: yes, but how do i get the content-length from 
InputStream is = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(); ?

I do not want to download the file locally...

Any ideas?

-Ash

Answer (score 0):

> I want to avoid copying the file
>   locally on my system before uploading
>   the file again

Well you're going to have to live with it, because that's how HTTP works. If you want to do remote-to-remote transfers, you're going to either use something other than HTTP (although I don't know of any protocol suitable for that), or remotely execute some software on one of the remote sites to perform the transfer.